# Methods of characteristic for system of first order linear hyperbolic partial differential equations: reference and examples

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

I would like to understand a few points on the methods of characteristics used to resolve a system of coupled, linear first order partial differential equation (of the hyperbolic type). Some example of them can be found

- [Method of characteristics for a system of pdes](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/799360/61950)
- [Solving a system of PDEs with method of characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/297648/61950)

on this website for instance.

So do you have any good reference about systems of first-order, coupled partial differential equation resolved via the method of characteristics.

Thanks in advance for any comment which would increase the quality of this question.

UPDATE: I've found some references like

- Courant, Methods of Mathematical physics (1962) - Willey & Sons
- Courant and Lax, [On nonlinear partial differential equations with two independent variables](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160020206) (1949) (beyond a paywall)
- John, Partial Differential Equations, 3-rd edition (1978) - Springer

but all discuss the non-linear problem, which obscure the presentation for my purpose. Is there no reference, good introduction to the topic for linear system ? In particular, simple examples would be well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a good reference I found:

- E.F. Toro, Riemann Solvers and Numerical Methods for Fluid Dynamics,
  DOI 10.1007/b7976-1 2, c Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2009

Chapter 2 is what you're looking for. You can find a [link online](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783540252023-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-718002-p52076107&ei=9ihkVKD9Oen1iQKg2IGIDw&usg=AFQjCNFuruTpF1Fmb8Mbjes8iMbcUgAwLw&sig2=mIyGHJLpUDHrNcWG6WDKnA&bvm=bv.79189006,d.cGE&cad=rja).

Answer (score 0):

I will add a one more:

Partial Differential Equations - Garabedian, John Wiley & Sons Inc., 1st edition, 1964 (there is also a newer edition)